# remove item from system.array in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

This is my `$array`:

```
Name          GUID 
----          ---- 
PC001         AAAA 
PC001         BBBB 
PC001         CCCC 
PC002         AAAA
PC002         DDDD
PC003         AAAA
PC003         CCCC
```

Here's my script:

```
$Guid = "CCCC"
$workingName = $array | where Guid -eq $Guid | select  name
$array.remove($workingName) #broke!
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that if `$Guid = "CCCC"` it would remove all instances of the `Name` and `CCCC` from the array, where `CCCC` exists, so in this instance five lines (three lines for PC001, two lines for PC0003), if it was `BBBB` it would only remove the three lines for PC001.

FYI: this is part of a much larger script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Guid = "CCCC"
$workingName = $array | where Guid -eq $Guid | select -ExpandProperty name
$array = $array | where { $_.name -notin $workingName }
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could create a new variable or just update the exiting one using a where statement.

```
$Array | ? {$_.GUID -ne 'CCCC'}
```

This will return the array back without the entries

Alternatively you can use methods, like you are trying to do there but you need to build the array a bit differently...here is an example.

```
$Proc = Get-Process | Select -first 2
$a = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$a.Add($Proc[0])
$a.Add($Proc[1])
$a
Write-Warning 'removing index 1'
$a.remove($Proc[1])
$a
```

Comment: $Array | ? {$_.GUID -ne 'CCCC'} doesn't do what the Ops wants. Not only should entries with that GUID be removed but also entries that have a name, which had an entry with that GUID. Given the ops example, your code would leave PC001 AAAA, PC001 BBBB and PC003 AAAA behind however the op wants those entries removed.

Comment: I had to read his post an unfortunate amount of times before that was clear...I guess an output example would have been helpful.

Comment: NoahSparks I'm sorry I wasn't clear, and I take and accept your point about giving an output example.  

I'm very grateful for your efforts (I voted up), and although I was aware that your answer didn't provide the exact output I needed, it did help me develop my own answer (which was extremely close to the answer @DanL gave, I just didn't have the `-notin` yet).  I'm also sorry I didn't have the change to update you until now, I was working on the problem at the same time in order to met a deadline.

Comment: It's alright, I am glad you were able to get it figured out.